Binary Cross Entropy Loss Not Learning Correct Indices
I am trying to implement a CNN that receives as input a 640 by 368 sized tensor where only the center 30 columns (i.e. columns 169 to 199) keep their real values and everything else is set to 0 and outputs a binarized (1s and 0s) tensor of size 338 essentially predicting what column indices in the input that were set to 0 are of importance.
The output layer uses a sigmoid activation and for the loss function I am using PyTorch's BCELoss:
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

for i in np.arange(nTrain):

   inputs = traindata[i]
   targets = train_masks[i]

   outputs = model(inputs)

   loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

The issue is, currently the model predicts the same output for all the inputs and is learning to match the number of 1s in the target tensor (usually 64) instead of getting the indices of these 1s right. Is the issue how my loss function is set up? How do I change it?
I tried adding another term to the loss function to minimize the error between the ground truth input tensor and the reconstruction of the image with the model's mask prediction applied to the the full input tensor without any column removals:

lamda*torch_nrmse(ground_truth, outputs(full_input))

However, that changed the mask prediction of the network, but it did not change the fact that the same singular mask is predicted for all inputs.
